# CorelDraw X7: How to remove all shapes which are outside selected shape.

Tags: shapes, coreldraw

I need to remove everything outside base shape (bold square). Base shape can have any shape. Is there a function where I can select base shape, click button and everything outside its borders will be disappeared? Is it possible to do in CorelDraw?

Example:

This is an original image:

[image]

I need following result:

[image]

Comment: Arrange-Sharping-Intersect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using a Powerclip. This is essentially a container for one or more objects, like a clipping path in Photoshop or Illustrator.
To achieve what you want:

1. Select all objects except the rectangle;
2. Use Object → Powerclip → Place inside frame;
3. Pick the rectangle.

Now you'll only see what's inside the container, limited by its borders. You can "enter" the container by right-clicking it and choosing "Edit powerclip"  (or CTRL-clicking the object). You can extract the contents to the main layer by right-clicking it and choosing "Extract contents".

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View -> Trim View`. It is useful to preview your design without elements that go beyond the edge of the artboard.